# Get data through pivot table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pivot

I got 3 tables. Table 1 & 2 has their ids as foreign keys in third one(pivot).

Relations for first one is

```
$this->hasMany("App\Pivot","game_id");
```

, second is

```
$this->belongsToMany("App\Pivot","army_id");
```

and pivot has relationships with both of them i.e `belongsTo`.

My schema:
[image: schema]

I tried accessing it in controller of first one like this:

```
$games= Game::with("armies")->get();
```

[image: armies]

Result that i get is array of games where instead of individual army data , i get collection from pivot table.

I can loop through it and get it that way, is there more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using pivot table this is the way how to do it.

Games Model

```
public function armies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Armies::class, 'pivot_table', 'game_id', 'army_id');
}
```

Armies Model

```
public function armies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Games::class, 'pivot_table', 'army_id', 'game_id');
}
```

Access the relationship like this..

Controller

```
App\Games::first()->armies()->get();
or
App\Games::first()->armies
or
App\Games::find(1)->armies
```

Comment: It works. I am using `$games = Game::with("armies")->get();`. I just want to ask you couple of follow ups. In array of armies, singular object has property pivots. Is it byproduct of relationship or is it removable? Second: If i remove `'army_id'` from first one you are written, it shows exactly the same data as with it. Why is that?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use an intermediate table like that I'd probably do something like this:

**Games model**

```
    public function armies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Armies');
    }
```

**Armies model**

```
    public function games()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Games');
    }
```

I'd keep the table structures all the same but rename the "pivot" table to armies_games since this is what Laravel will look for by default. If you want to keep it named Pivots, you'll need to pass it in as the second argument in `belongsToMany`.

With this, you don't really need the Pivot model, you should just be able to do:

```
$armies = Game::first()->armies()->get();
```

or

```
$armies = Game::find(3)->armies()->orderBy('name')->get();
```

or

```
$game = Game::first();
foreach ($game->armies as $army) {
  //
}
```

etc.

Comment: Not really applicable. I don't "know" in advance id. Plus it for all 'games' respectively. I said i'm trying avoiding loops and searching more "laravel way" of doing it.

Comment: The answer posted 10 minutes after mine explains exactly what I explained almost verbatim. I'm curious as why mine is "not applicable" but the other was accepted?

Comment: Because my pivot table is called "pivot", not standard Laravel naming i.e. "army_game". This is my fault. Didn't know about pivot table naming convection. Your would work if it were standard named.